# Modify current URL without page refresh in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

Can anyone help me to solve my task.

I have two search boxes in my webpage, and when the user enter some keywords and press the submit button i want to replace my url from
 **www.domain.com/search**    into

**www.domain.com/search/keywod1-sometext-keyword2.**

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and especially read Why is [“Can someone help me?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) not an actual question?

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to put pushstate inside a `try` in case some webbrowsers don't support it.  Additionally, you don't have any real need to set your histoy title, in most instances, but if you want to: `history.pushState(null, 'title', newLoc);`

```
<script>
newLoc = "I/like/to/eat";
try {
        history.pushState(null, null, newLoc);
} catch(e) {}
location.hash = '#' + newLoc;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ajax there to get the result data from database, and on success block of your ajax, you can use the following code:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

See [*Manipulating the browser history* on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method):

> `pushState()` takes three parameters: a state object, a title (which is currently ignored), and (optionally) a URL.
>
> - state object
> - title
> - URL
>
> **state object —** The state object is a JavaScript object which is associated with the new history entry created by pushState(). Whenever the user navigates to the new state, a popstate event is fired, and the state property of the event contains a copy of the history entry's state object.
>
> The state object can be anything that can be serialized. Because Firefox saves state objects to the user's disk so they can be restored after the user restarts the browser, we impose a size limit of 640k characters on the serialized representation of a state object. If you pass a state object whose serialized representation is larger than this to pushState(), the method will throw an exception. If you need more space than this, you're encouraged to use sessionStorage and/or localStorage.
>
> **title —** Firefox currently ignores this parameter, although it may use it in the future. Passing the empty string here should be safe against future changes to the method. Alternatively, you could pass a short title for the state to which you're moving.
>
> **URL —** The new history entry's URL is given by this parameter. Note that the browser won't attempt to load this URL after a call to pushState(), but it might attempt to load the URL later, for instance after the user restarts the browser. The new URL does not need to be absolute; if it's relative, it's resolved relative to the current URL. The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise, pushState() will throw an exception. This parameter is optional; if it isn't specified, it's set to the document's current URL.

Comment: I can't use form submission using AJAX due to some specific reasons in this current webpage. So i  am searching for some other methods. I have done my submission using normal PHP Form submit.

Comment: you have to go for js for client side modifications.